# Make image, size/align itself relative to Heading?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html/css (I know Javascript), and this is my first real attempt at a page.  The image is huge, I want it to size itself relative to the full window/container size, and align itself center with the container/window.  I want to be able to size it if possible with a % number if I'm correct in my thinking.  I know I have to move the image into the main body, below the heading.  Will my image inherit its responsive properties (i.e. width adjust, alignment) from my main-background through heading?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mac Miller Tribute</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\geek\Desktop\New-Site\CSS\sytles.css">
</head>

<div class="main-image">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Miller" target="_blank">
  <img src="C:\Users\geek\Desktop\New-Site\Images\macmiller.jpg" alt="Mac miller picture" >
</a>
</div>

<div class="main-background">

    <h1 class="heading">Mac Miller Tribute</h1>
    <body>
        <p class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding 'width="100%"' to your image-Tag?

```
<img width="100%" src="C:\Users\geek\Desktop\New-Site\Images\macmiller.jpg" alt="Mac miller picture" >
```

This should allow your picture to resize accordingly, while always staying  at 100% of the container's size.

Comment: Thanks, answered my question.  What exactly does this magic do tho?  I set the width to a max percentage in-line, so it always resizes relative to the set pixel size of its parent element?

Comment: It simply tells the image's width to always stay at 100% of the surrounding container's size. The image's height is not explicitly declared so the browser is using the image file's aspect ratio to calculate it.